# Error:Expected caller to ensure valid ABI: ARM64_V8A

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-ndk

I'm new to Android NDK development. Today I set up a project through Android Studio Wizard, What's different from common Sdk development is that I checked "Include C++ Support".Then enter development zone,it info me gradle sync failed--- "Error:Expected caller to ensure valid ABI: ARM64_V8A".

My develop evironment is :

Android Studio2.2.2

JRE:1.8.0

OS:Windows 10 family version

The error log as below:

```
2016-11-23 11:35:03,111 [12186031]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - Expected caller to ensure valid ABI: ARM64_V8A 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Expected caller to ensure valid ABI: ARM64_V8A
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.createUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.java:106)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.java:579)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:158)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.getUserFriendlyError(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:405)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:772)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:752)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:238)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:112)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:73)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:51)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:138)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:419)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:500)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:369)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

After my careful search ,I find it add some content in build.gradle(app)

```
   externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "CMakeLists.txt"
    }
}
```

After you delete it,it's ok. It's content is as below:

```
    # Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native
# library. You should either keep the default value or only pass a
# value of 3.4.0 or lower.

#cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)


# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds it for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
         native-lib

         # Sets the library as a shared library.
         SHARED

         # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
         # Associated headers in the same location as their source
         # file are automatically included.
         src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )

# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because system libraries are included in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
          log-lib

          # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
          # you want CMake to locate.
          log )

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in the
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                   native-lib

                   # Links the target library to the log library
                   # included in the NDK.
                   ${log-lib} )
```

I have reported it to [Android Studio bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=228916).

I don't know if it's my fault.Any explanation is appreciated.

Comment: I got this error last week as well. This seems to be tied to a new version of AS :| A colleague of mine got it to work by going File -> Invalidate Caches/ Restart, while it didn't work for me.

Comment: @Sipty It doesn't work for me.

Comment: What about attempting to update to a nightly build of AS? Or reverting to an older version? I am 99% sure this is a version bug, rather than a user error!!!

Comment: My condition belongs to 1%, I'm just updated now version  is 2.2.3 . This is my new summition https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=229781&thanks=229781&ts=1481177346

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today, when I import "echo" an ndk example, it warned me

> Error:Expected NDK STL shared object file at E:\Android_Sdk\ndk-bundle\sources\cxx-stl\llvm-libc++\libs\armeabi-v7a\libc++_shared.so

After searching my computer and another computer ndk-build directory, I found the problem.
It's caused by my carelessness, I copied ndk-build directory from another computer, but it wasn't a comeplete copy. After copying again the problem dismissed.

I'm really sorry for my carelessness. I don't know if it need to delete this post.If need, please not hesitate to tell me.

Comment: If like me you googled this error and got here, maybe like me you had set `ANDROID_NDK_PATH=/path/to/sdk/` instead of `ANDROID_NDK_PATH=/path/to/sdk/ndk-bundle/`?